# Excel VBA: CTRL + F as a macro

Tags: vba, excel

This code searches data on Sheet2 and if it finds it on Sheet2,
it copies full row on Sheet1.

I would like to edit it: 
so when I search for example "John%Wayne"
it looks for cells that contain and John and Wayne in its string.

```
Sub myFind()
'Standard module code, like: Module1.
'Find my data and list found rows in report!
Dim rngData As Object
Dim strDataShtNm$, strReportShtNm$, strMySearch$, strMyCell$
Dim lngLstDatCol&, lngLstDatRow&, lngReportLstRow&, lngMyFoundCnt&

On Error GoTo myEnd
'*******************************************************************************
strDataShtNm = "Sheet2" 'This is the name of the sheet that has the data!
strReportShtNm = "Sheet1" 'This is the name of the report to sheet!
'*******************************************************************************
Sheets(strReportShtNm).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Define data sheet's data range!
Sheets(strDataShtNm).Select

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
lngLstDatRow = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1
lngLstDatCol = .Columns.Count + .Column - 1
End With

Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lngLstDatRow, lngLstDatCol))

'Get the string to search for!
strMySearch = InputBox("Enter what to search for, below:" & vbLf & vbLf & _
"Note: The search is case sensitive!", _
Space(3) & "Find All", _
"")

'Do the search!
For Each Cell In rngData
strMyCell = Cell.Value

'If found then list entire row!
If strMyCell = strMySearch Then
lngMyFoundCnt = lngMyFoundCnt + 1
ActiveSheet.Rows(Cell.Row & ":" & Cell.Row).Copy

With Sheets(strReportShtNm)
'Paste found data's row!
lngReportLstRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=.Range("A" & lngReportLstRow).EntireRow
End With
End If
Next Cell

myEnd:
'Do clean-up!
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets(strReportShtNm).Select

'If not found then notify!
If lngMyFoundCnt = 0 Then
MsgBox """" & strMySearch & """" & Space(3) & "Was not found!", _
vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
Space(3) & "Not Found!"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `like` or `instr`

Comment: you can use the [`split`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) to split `strMySearch` with the divider `%` into an array `arrMySearch` and then loop through that array and compare with `strMyCell`

Comment: if you use the wildcard `*` you can say `if x like *john*wayne*`  the grey areas, like John Wayne, Johnathan Wayne etc, will need thinking about also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Find` with the `*` wildcard (or if you really want to use % then replace % with * in the code):

```
Sub myFind()

    Dim rToSearch As Range
    Dim sMySearch As String
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    'Get the string to search for!
    sMySearch = InputBox("Enter what to search for, below:" & vbLf & vbLf & _
    "Note: The search is case sensitive!", _
    Space(3) & "Find All", _
    "")

    With ThisWorkbook
        'Set reference to data in column A.
        With .Worksheets("Sheet2")
            Set rToSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious))
        End With
        'Find the last row containing data in Sheet 1.
        With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
            On Error Resume Next
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1
            On Error GoTo 0
            If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1
        End With
    End With

    'Use find to search your text.
    'FindNext will, strangely enough, find the next occurrence and keep looping until it
    'reaches the top again - and back to the first found address.
    With rToSearch
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=sMySearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                rFound.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lLastRow, 1)
                lLastRow = lLastRow + 1
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It breaks on: With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Set rToSearch = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Columns(1).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious))

Comment: Does it break with a `1004 Application-defined or object-defined error`? Or is it a syntax error - 1004 error could be the sheet is empty, syntax error is that `With .Worksheets("Sheet1")` is one line, `Set rToSearch....` is the next line.  Are the sheets named `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`?

Comment: On Set rToSearch, 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Could be failing because `Sheet1` is empty.  The code is working on `ThisWorkbook` which is the file containing the code.  It may be looking at the wrong `Sheet1`.  If it's meant to be looking at another file try using `With Workbooks("book_name.xlsx")` or `With ActiveWorkBook`.

Comment: Sheet1 should be destination, and Sheet2 contains data.

Comment: That should be it then - I've updated the code and swapped `Sheet1` & `Sheet2` around.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it.

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to accept it as the answer, vote it up and shower it with confetti... or something like that.  :)

Comment: Yes, I would do that, but it doesn't allow me, cause I'm not a registered user. And also, for example if I enter "John" it return me also "Johnny" and so on, and I'd like to have only exact searches, but I will try to do it myself tomorrow if I figure out the code.